# How Do I Decipher This Ciphertext?

Tags: block-cipher, decryption

**Ciphertext**:1rUHjDnJs09VNvxLiWZzL7PXeKUHvxFVG5GT59WdS6nvOZ1UypVbKlQTcl4orHFShQMBCFGH8+4+SlFDDv4+dUIcmd3zyaBnsXKCb9lMuGmMJkslgPFvgPKNWGsSVu4BhI6/42dGG3q0Lca465xeDaEKTj3Yan/59/+D5Sd6Cha3qwEWoITbR8zFgFNcOVLR

**Key**:3917249

I was given this as a scenario for as an assignment, I've tried everything in the book to the best of my knowledge to decipher this ciphertext using e.g. online cipher detector tools, hash identifier and, frequency analyser, still couldn't decipher it. It's supposed to contain some sort of link to a target machine. But in order to obtain that link, the ciphertext must first be deciphered.

Here are my findings: the ciphertext is base64 encoded, Key length is 7 bytes, the ciphertext contains 192 characters.

**My Question Now Is What Do I Need To Do / What Have I Missed?**

Comment: The base64 decode is simple, but now you need to know what encryption was used. I ran it through all openssl supported ciphers, and it didn't like any of them. What other encryption algorithms did you cover? It's probably going to be one from one of your classes. Maybe one created in class? What if the base64 needs a substitution applied before it decodes properly? Homework is tough. I'd love to know the answer.